# HTML button with JavaScript function to change BG color

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to make an html button that executes a JavaScript function to change background color.

Here's what I have code wise:

```
<button onclick = "backgroundChange()">Press Me</button>

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

function backgroundChange () {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
    }
    else if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";  
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong boys?

Comment: I know you have just accepted an answer - but checkout  my solution - gives the same result without any if statements :) BTW - @Hek mat was totally correct with the solution provided to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make proper comparison using equality(`==`) instead of assignment(`=`) operator.document.

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
var btn = document.querySelector('button');//it selects your button element you can also select using id,class,..
btn.onclick = function() //handles the click event
{

    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
    }
    else if(document.body.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";  
    }

}
```

```html
<button onclick = "backgroundChange()">Press Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to not use if statements. You can increment the count on the button with each click and then use the modulus operator to determine the color from an array based on the value of the button.

```js
function backgroundChange (index) {
  var colors= ["white","red"];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index %2];
  document.getElementById('changeButton').value = parseInt(index)+1;
  }
```

```html
<button id="changeButton" onclick = "backgroundChange(this.value)" value="1">Press Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare anything, always use `==` instead of `=`.

Try this:

```
if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
}
else if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";  
}
```